# python timer and disable function

Tags: python, function, timer

i have a function thats gets executed when the script is run. this function is called main()

```
timer = 0
def main():
   function2()
   function3()
   timer()
```

this function calls the following functions: function2, function3, and timer.

```
def timer():
    global timer
    while timer < 120:
        timer += 1
        timer.sleep(1)
        print timer
        if timer == 120:
            timer = 0
            function2 = false
```

the problem is that the timer doesn't print in the console. and function2 doesn't get disabled after 120 seconds.

what am i doing wrong? any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: The `timer` variable seems ambiguous.

Comment: let me add the timer variable

Comment: It looks like `timer` is 1) an int, 2) a function, 3) misspelled `time` module.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work like that, a) because `function2` is a local variable in `timer`, and b) because `timer` isn't run asynchronously. Also no variable called `timer` will be accessible inside the function, because it itself is named `timer`.

If you want to interrupt `function2` after 120 seconds, you should just set a timer (`time.time()`) at the beginning of `function2` and then in the loop that I assume resides in `function2` check for whether the current time is more than 120 ahead of the time initially recorded upon entering the function. In that case, you can `return` from that function to stop it.

**edit:** This would be an example:

```
import time

def function2():
    timer = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - timer > 120:
            return # time to exit from this function
        print("We are doing something!")
        time.sleep(1) # just for demonstration

def function3():
    pass # do something else

if __name__ == '__main__': # better than a function called "main"
    function2()
    function3()
```

Comment: oke i kinda get what u mean. but i am a bit of  a newb to programming in general. could you give me a quick sketch of your explanation in code? that would be great :)

Comment: thanks for the answer! ill see if it works! and if it does ill let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the logic of your code, but the first thing you need to do is disambiguate your variables, e.g.:

```
import time

timer_ = 0

def timer():
    global timer_
    while timer_ < 120:
        timer_ += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print timer_
        if timer_ == 120:
            timer_ = 0
            function2 = lambda: False

def main():
    function2()
    function3()
    timer()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! ill take a look at it and see if it works in my code. ill let you know if it worked.